# Android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Is there a way to make sure that the latest google services are installed on the device? and if not not show the maps on the application and not have the application crash?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call:

```
int code = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();

if(code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    // google play services are up to date
} else {
    // get dialog to fix issue
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this, REQUEST_GPS_ERROR_DIALOG);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return false;
        }else{
                   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    9000).show();
            }
        return true;
    }
```